# Levels of indirection error

Tags: c

I'm trying to create code that stores inputs into a structured array that allocates memory every time it performs `fgets`. This is what I have done so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct listings{
    int index;
    char *text;
};

int main(){
    int len;
    int i;
    int indexnum;
    char input[255];
    struct listings *p;
    char *q, *r;
    indexnum = 0;
    q = &input[255];
    //p = &listing[indexnum].text;

    for(;;){
        printf("Input a Word: \n");
        q = fgets(input, 255, stdin);
        printf("word: %s", q);
        if(q != NULL){
            len = strlen(input);
            p = (struct listings *) calloc(1,sizeof(char)*(len+1));
            p->text[indexnum] = q; //Error here

            printf("listing: %s\n", p->text[indexnum]);
            indexnum++;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code (just to see if I'm on the right track), it shows up a error on the line

```
p->text[indexnum] = q;
```

**saying :** `warning C4047 'char' differs in levels of indirection from 'char *'`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

`p->text[indexnum]` is a character, not a string.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Do you want a string array ? If so, you must declare `text` as a `char**`, allocate the array first (`malloc(sizeof(char*) * ARRAY_SIZE)`) then allocate each string inside it.

If you just want to fill `text` with `q`, use strings functions, like `strcpy`.

Answer (score 1):

```
p->text[indexnum] = q;
```

The type of `p->text[indexnum]` is `char` but you are assigning it a `char *` (the type of `q`).

You have the same issue here:

```
 printf("listing: %s\n", p->text[indexnum]);
```

`s` requires a `char *` argument but `p->text[indexnum]` is of type `char`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(){
    int len;
    int i;
    int indexnum;
    char input[255];
    struct listings p[16];
    char *q, *r;
    indexnum = 0;

    for(;;){
        printf("Input a Word: \n");
        q = fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin);
        if(q != NULL){
            printf("word: %s\n", q);
            len = strlen(input);
            p[indexnum].text = malloc(len+1);
            strcpy(p[indexnum].text, q);

            printf("listing: %s\n", p[indexnum].text);
            ++indexnum;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<indexnum;++i){
        printf("%s", p[i].text);
        free(p[i].text);
    }
    return 0;
}
```